# Three gestures crash my iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, swipe, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have problem with swipe with three gestures

in my .m :

```c
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {

    [_text setText:@"Hello World"];
}

- (IBAction)resetText:(id)sender {

    [_text setText:@"Reset"];
}
```

when I clicked on the screen the output message "Hello World" will be shown on label
and it should shown "Reset" when I swipe three fingers from up to down, but it crashes

the weird thing is when I change the name of IBAction from "resetText" to for example "reset" or whatever name without capital letter it works. With any capital letter, it crashes

[this is the Xcode file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12605533/Test.zip)

Comment: What does the crash log say? Also, what are you clicking and what are you clicking with? A mouse? Or are you "tapping" the screen?

Comment: sorry I'm newbie, I dont know where the crash log file is. I'm using my iPhone to test the app, so I'm tapping on screen.

Comment: The crash log is in the console in Xcode. When it crashes look at the bit at the bottom of the Xcode window. This will have lots of text in it.

Comment: the log says nothing but: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12605533/2013-07-09%2001.32.58%20pm.png

Comment: by the way, how can I simulate three fingers in the iOS simulator?

Comment: You are not supposed to change the name of the method after you make a connection using IB. @Boss

Comment: First, you need to find the crash log. It'll be at the bottom of the Xcode window. If it isn't, find the button that looks like a bit like ⏏ on the bar at the bottom, and click it. A panel containing the console log should appear.

Comment: @m177312: I know how change it and modify other things. Anyway, even if I do this with a new project project it is the same. I mean if I create new project named IBAction "resetText", it will crash; and if I create new project named IBAction "reset" it wont crash.

Comment: @Boss please post the crash log as per the instructions I just posted so we can have a look and try to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite: there are nothing in log. you can see my screenshot https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12605533/2013-07-09%2001.32.58%20pm.png

Comment: @Boss if you press the |> arrow in the bar above the console a few times, you should get a stack trace printed to the console.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite I have pressed "Continue Program Execution" forever but nothing change :(

Comment: @Boss strange. Doing that or disabling breakpoints and continuing execution should usually crash the program and print a crash log to the console.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite Yes you write it should shown me crash log but with this crash not. how can I simulate three fingers in iOS simulator? may be I will have crash log in simulator. by the way I have put my xcode project, you can try it

Comment: @Boss it doesn't crash for me.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite What?strang! may be the problem with my iPhone. Do you use iPhone for testing or the simulator? which iPhone do you have? and which iOS ver.?

Comment: @PartiallyFinite have you swipe with three fingers from up to down and word "Reset" is shown without crash?

Comment: @Boss I finally got it to crash on an iPad 3 running iOS 6.1.3. I'll investigate this and post back here a bit later.

Comment: @Boss looks like the crash is somewhere inside `UIGestureRecognizer`. Here's the stack trace: http://cl.ly/image/3w2x0R1q1Z2Z. I'll try and find out what's causing it.

Comment: @Boss and here's a full crash log: http://cl.ly/0N1g2j2K121S

Comment: @PartiallyFinite How could you find a crash log? for me I cant find it

Comment: @Boss I ran it on my iPad manually (by opening from the home screen), and crashed it. Then I got the log by going into Organiser > Devices > iPad > Device Logs

Comment: @PartiallyFinite any Progressing?

Comment: @Boss I was busy all day, finally got round to looking at it now. Hopefully I'll find a fix soon.

Comment: @Boss it seems that it only crashes when the gesture is 3 or more fingers. It works fine with 1 and 2. Looks like there's a bug in Apple's implementation. You should [file a bug with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your example project, and it seems that:

- The crash only occurs on actual devices
- The crash only occurs when the swipe gesture requires 3 or more touches

This looks to me like a bug in the `UIGestureRecognizer` class when added using Interface Builder, so there isn't much you can do about it now. I filed a radar (#14399827) with Apple describing this issue. You should probably [do this](http://bugreport.apple.com) as well.

---

However, you can work around this bug by creating the gesture recogniser in code instead of in the storyboard as you are now.

Remove the gesture recogniser from your storyboard (delete it completely), then add this to the `viewDidLoad` method in your view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recogniser = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resetText:)];
    [recogniser setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
    [recogniser setNumberOfTouchesRequired:3];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recogniser];
}
```

I understand that this isn't ideal, as it may be more convenient in some cases to add the view controller directly to the storyboard, but unfortunately it seems that you can't currently do that due a bug in Apple's implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping :). I'll report to Apple

Comment: @Boss my report just got closed, so they're already aware of it and it'll be fixed in a future iOS version. But for now, you'll have to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your view controller and now it is working for all gestures you want. Please check out and let me know.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
//gesture for tap
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(click)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

//gesture for right swipe
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
[rightRecognizer release]; 

//gesture for right swipe
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
[leftRecognizer release];}


- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{ [_text setText:@" World"]; }

- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{ [_text setText:@"World"]; }

- (void)click{ [_text setText:@"Hello World"]; }
```

Comment: this does not solve my problem. my code is work perfectly if I write:  - (IBAction)reset:(id)sender {

    [_text setText:@"Reset"];
} or  write - (IBAction)yesss:(id)sender {

    [_text setText:@"Reset"];
} but it crash if I write: - (IBAction)resetText:(id)sender {

    [_text setText:@"Reset"];
} or: - (IBAction)writeReset:(id)sender {

    [_text setText:@"Reset"];
}. my problem why it crash with capital letter and not if i use small letter only.

Comment: It is a bug in the UIGestureRecognizer class when added using Interface Builder. the crash it will not happened with all devices, may be that's why you are not getting any crash. Anyway Apple has respond with it and may be it will be fixed with next update of SDK. Thanks for your help